# MySql column without aggregates and group by clause

Tags: mysql, group-by

Since I am coming from MSSQL world I am confused, what happening in queries where you have group by clause and other columns in select which do not go through aggregates functions.

I was shocked when MySql executed query like this

```
select * from myTable
group by columnThatIsNotPk
```

Or fiddle like this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b30bf5/1

My questions are:

1. Is there an explanation which data I am going to get for columns that not exists in group by clause?
2. Is it ok to use queries like that?
3. Do I lose or gain performances with queries like this?
4. Does MySql implements First and Last aggregates as it does JetEngine in ACCESS, and unfortunately missing feature in MSSQL engine?

Comment: You get random data. Welcome to MySQL! It's actually fixed in the latest version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the question about aggregates:  See `only_full_group_by`, which was added in MySQL 5.7.5.  Before that, you got random values for the columns not based on the `GROUP BY` column(s).  After that, the statement is in error (unless you turn off that flag).

As for whether there is a performance gain?  Who cares, if you get garbage?  `SELECT *` is probably never faster (other than to type) than `SELECT ...` with specific columns.

As for `FIRST`, `LAST`, and other "Windowing functions", they are available in MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0 (but not yet ready for prime time).  There are workarounds, often using `LIMIT 1`.

Another thing to learn about if you are moving to MySQL:  Learn about `AUTO_INCREMENT` as a non-drop-in replacement `SEQUENCEs`.